# Check if 2 files content is equal

Tags: c, system-calls, file-descriptor

Been asked to get 2 files, and with a file descriptor - check each character on both and see if equals, if even 1 character from file n.1 is different from file n.2 - return 1, if both files have the same content - return 2, if there's any situation(issues) except what I mentioned - return 0/1.

My problem is that the program returns 2 every time, both if the 2 files have this content: "abcd" or even if one file has: "abcd" and the other have: "abcg"/"abc" .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    if(argc != 3)
        return 0;
    
    int fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    int fd2 = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    
    if(fd1 == -1 || fd2 == -1)
        return 0;
    
    char c1, c2;
    
    if(read(fd1, &c1, 1) == 0 || read(fd2, &c2, 1) == 0)
        return 1;
    if(c1 != c2)
            return 1;
    
    while(read(fd1, &c1, 1) == 0 || read(fd2, &c2, 1) == 0){
        if(c1 != c2)
            return 1;
    }
    
    return 2;
}
```

Thanks in advance guys, and sorry for the grammar mistakes, English isn't my main language.

Comment: To paraphrase the while: `while(at_end_of_file(fd1) || at_end_of_file(fd2))` -- if the files are longer than one character, the loop won't be entered at all.

Comment: @dratenik Hey, thanks for the quick response :)
Can you please explain further about that? I'm pretty new to that

Comment: There's no reason to check the first character separately, toss the `if read...`. And you need to rethink the loop.

Comment: Also it's very inefficient to read the files byte per byte. You should read larger chunks (maybe 64 K at a time) and compare these chunks, for example with [`memcmp`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/)

Comment: @Jabberwocky , My teacher told us to do that task with checking each character, and I still don't get why the program return only 2, and not 1 if the files aren't the same by the content they have :/

Comment: @RyanOtweeng OK, if your teacher told you so, no problem, it's not wrong, just inefficient. For your actual problem: read closely the documentation of `read` especially the part that deals with the return value. Also as a comment already mentioned: remove the 4 lines before the while loop, it's useless, there is nothing special about the the first character.

Comment: Ryan Otweeng, With `while(read(fd1, &c1, 1) == 0 || read(fd2, &c2, 1) == 0){`, why continue the loop if the read count is zero?

Comment: @RyanOtweeng With `while(read(fd1, &c1, 1) == read(fd2, &c2, 1)){`, why continue the while loop if both streams read 0 bytes?

Comment: An exit status of 2 when the files are equal is strange. Normally you'd want to return 0 in that case like `cmp(1)` does.

Answer (score 1):

This is the pseudo code you need, assuming you want to read the files byte per byte:

```
  repeat
    read one byte from file 1
    read one byte from file 2
    
    if you did not read the same number of bytes from both files,
    the files are different and you can stop

    if the number of bytes read is 0, you're at the end of the files,
    the files have the same content and you can stop

    if bytes read are different, the file are different and you can stop

  end of repeat
```

Hint: the `read` functions returns the number of bytes read, in your case it's either 1 if the byte was successfully read, or 0 if it's the end of the file.

Comment: How do I return 1 if I entered the while loop and on the 1st operation both starting characters are different by value(c1 != c2) ? where can I return 1? because right now, if it happens - It'll return 2, And that's why I made a check of the first characters before entering the while loop.
(Code edited by the way :) )

Comment: @RyanOtweeng Changing the question after answers arrive is poor Stack overflow etiquette.  You are creating a moving target.  Please revert the code.

Comment: Sorry about that, pretty new to the rules.

Comment: @RyanOtweeng don't treat the first character differently. Just apply by pseudo code.

Comment: What makes the while loop to stop?

Comment: @RyanOtweeng _"What makes the while loop to stop? "_ not sure what you're asking here. You can stop a while loop anywhere with  the `break` statement, like `if (somecondition) break; ...`